# Rails - ability to link directly to views that are rendered via ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

Looking for the best way to implement this.  Currently I have a "show" page for Users - that shows all of a users' pictures.

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @pictrues = @user.pictures
end
```

On that page, I have various tabs.  When a user clicks on one of those tabs, an ajax call renders a view... particularly, it updates a partial that was previously showing all of a users pictures (and an additional partial for statistics).  For the "show comments" example, it updates the partial with all of the pictures a user has commented on:

```
def show_comments
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @pictures = @user.picture_comments.map{ |p| p.picture }.uniq
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

The show_comments.js.erb file looks like:

```
$("#user_content_container").html("<%= escape_javascript render(partial: 'shared/pictures', pictures: @pictures) %>");
$("div.user_header").html("<h4>Comments</h4><br/>");
$("#stat_container").html("<%= escape_javascript render(partial: 'shared/comment_stats', pictures: @pictures) %>");
```

What I want to do, is to keep the current functionality of the page.  But also be able to link directly to the views that are rendered via ajax.  For example, have a link on another page that goes directly to the users "show" page, as it is when the "comments" tab is clicked on.

I have a few ideas, but an not sure what the "cleanest" way of doing this would be.  Let me know if you need any additional clarification, b/c I'm honestly having as difficult time wording this question, as I am in finding the best way to implement this!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something that you might be able to solve using [turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks).  If you can update your app to use Rails 4, you get this bundled in.  Otherwise, you can use the gem.  For more information on how to do this, watch the [railscast on turbolinks](http://railscasts.com/episodes/390-turbolinks).

If you don't want to or can't use them, you could also try passing params in the url, and check for them when the page is loaded.  You could use the params to modify the page in the same way that it would be modified after the AJAX call.